# How to grab data in each row within the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help writing VBA code that will grab all the data within a cell and paste it separately somewhere else to reference later to be used. I have a cell of data that has multiple rows of data in it. For example in Cell A1 I have this stack of data.

```
21ABC
22DCF
19CVD
...
```

I want to be able to date that data and split it into its own cells. Preferably in different columns.
So the above data will go from A1 (1 single cell of data) to 3 separate cells.

```
D1    | E1    | F1
21ABC | 22DCF | 19CVD
```

I've tried vbNewline, shifting and offsets and haven't been able to figure out a way to grab the data and split it up properly.

Comment: Voting to close as needs minimum debugging information.  Please provide the code you have used thusfar.

Comment: Why don't you share your attempt (as text) where you used `vbNewLine`? It probably needs just a simple fix something like `Range("D1:F1").Value = Split(Range("A1").Value, vbLf)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In Excel under the Data tab you go to "Text to Columns" and then "Delimit" under Delimiters select other "Ctrl + J" for new column.
The VBA code would be like this.

```
    Range("A1:A25").TextToColumns _
   Destination:=Range("A1:A25"), 
   DataType:=xlDelimited, _
   TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
   ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
   Tab:=False, _
   Semicolon:=False, _
   Comma:=False, 
   Space:=True, _
   Other:=False, _
   FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), _
   DecimalSeparator:="." , _
   ThousandsSeparator:=",", _ 
   TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```